# Unable to have Zsh as a login shell at Screen's startup

Tags: zsh, gnu-screen

I put the following to my .zshrc

```
if [[ $STY = '' ]] then screen -xR; fi
```

I get Bash when I start terminal now, although I have /bin/zsh at Terminal > Settings in Mac.

**Which variable do I need to change to make Zsh my login shell in Screen?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fast way to change your shell, for example to Zsh, is to run the following code

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

Answer (score 2):

- Open your **System Preferences**.
- Click on **Accounts**.
- Click on the **lock icon** that says "Click the lock to make changes".
- **Control-click** or right click on your **account name** in the list of accounts on the left.
- Choose the **Advanced Options...** menu item.
- Change your **login shell** to `/bin/zsh`.
- Close and reopen any shells in **Terminal.app**.

Answer (score 1):

If environment and other things aren't working, then you can simply give it as an argument to screen: `screen -xR zsh` and screen will run zsh instead of something else (bash).

Answer (score 0):

```
SHELL=/bin/zsh screen
```

should work, i. e. set the environment variabe `$SHELL`

Comment: @mihi: It seems that the difference with your command to chsh -command is that your command makes the shell temporarily zsh, while chsh makes it as long as you run another chsh -command.

Comment: yeah, right. The difference is what happens to your normal login shell. There are cases where some remote tools that log you in via ssh require a bash or ksh shell, so you cannot globally change your shell. You can still open a screen with zsh's in it (in fact, you can also open a shell with for example Midnight Commanders in it) with this method.